# External Drive Shows in Sys.Profiler but Won't Mount/absent from DiskUtility (OSX 10 & 11)

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, mount, format

I have a Sandisk 1TB Extreme USB-C external SSD that I bought and filled with an important 900GB dataset on about 16 months ago. I have not used it since. I have probably updated my mac OS to several versions later on both of my macs since I put accessed/filled the drive.

Today, I finally got around to trying to make a backup copy of it and I discovered:

- It won't mount on either of my macs---a newish MBP running OS 11.6 or an old mac running 10.13 (via the Sandisk's USB-C to USB adapter).
- On both macs, the drive shows up with basic information in System Profiler under USB devices (pic attached), but the 'Media' section of this info is missing.
- It does not appear on Disk Utility at all (view external drives is enabled).

Could this be a formatting issue, esp. since I upgraded my OS a few times since I used the drive? What more can I do? I really need the data set on it.

[image]

Comment: Update:  sudo pkill -f fsck   does nothing

Comment: Update: I tried mounting it on a windows machine. Windows shows the drive and says it's 'functioning properly', but it will not mount (so no file access)

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that there is a formatting issue relating to an OS update, especially as you note similar symptoms on two Macs, each with different macOS versions.

The fact that the Windows PC sees the drive but will not mount is unsurprising as Windows has no native APFS or HFS+ support.

You don't mention what you formatted it as so I am assuming APFS or HFS+ here...

It sounds like there are a couple of hardware issues possible. The drive itself could have failed, or the case and its electronics has failed. The only way to test those possibilities is to put the drive into another *known good* case.

Whoops let's add another possibility, have you tried another cable?

After trying those things, if the drive is still inaccessible you can try some data recovery software or sending the drive off to a data recovery specialist. Though the last option can get expensive quickly.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  I can't recall whether I formatted the drive before using it---I believe this model is natively exFAT I think. I usually reformat to a mac format, but I was in a rush getting that dataset.  I have tried numerous cables that are all verified/working with other drives. Pardon my ignorance, but what does it mean to put the drive into another case? I have done that with HDD's, but this is a little SSD. Is the idea that they USB-C port may have partially failed or similar?

Comment: You just need a case that will take the SSD, same idea, you just have to determine what connector is on the SSD by opening it first. If it still does not work then, it is likely a failure of the SSD of some sort.